# De-Code a python program

Tags: python, decode, encode

I have a python program which i cannot edit. It askes for 'What is the current encoding for this file' in order to edit it.

Does anyone know how to de-code this
This is what i see when i open the file with notepad.

```
    ¾ÀA PQèk  ƒÄ…Àt¹ÀA ‹    ;u‹øH‹E+ÁD0üëÏ‹Ç_]ÃU‹ìƒì,Wh@ê@ Eü3ÿh`A P‰}ü‰}ðèç  3É;Ç”ÁhHê@ Qè ÿÿÿjWÿuüè  ÿuüè' 
™‰EèüþÿÿƒÄ$‰Uì‰Eø;Ç}‰}øSVWÿuøÿuüèï  ÿuü»  SjÿuèÛ
```

ÿu‹ðè3ÿÿÿƒÄ ;Çt‹ðjY}Ôó¥‹}+ÇEø™‹ð‰Uìé   ¾  Vè7  ‰Eô‹Eè
    ðûY‰Eø;Ç}‰}øWÿuøÿuüè  ÿuüVjÿuôèr
  ÿuô‹ðèÊþÿÿ‹ð3À;÷•Àhdê@ ‰uìPèIþÿÿ‹Eì+EôjEøYÿuô™}Ôó¥‹ð‰UìèM  ‹}ƒÄ,+uä+uà+óy3öj Vÿuüè  ÿuüSjWè

```
‹ð3À;ÆÀ÷Øhˆê@ PèìýÿÿƒÄ$D>ÿ^[ëf‹¹¤ê@ f;tH;Çsîë‰Eðÿuüè´  ‹EðY_ÉÃU‹ìV‹ðÿÐ@ ƒ& jjj VPÿuPÿ@Ð@ ‹ð…öuÿ8Ð@ ƒøuF‹Æ^]ÃU‹ìƒ} u¡hA …Àt  
j PÿÐ@ 3À@]ÃU‹ìƒäøìÜ   ¡„A 3Ä‰„$Ø   ‹ESVW3ÿWW‰D$ÿ0Ð@ ‹ØD$PjpD$xPj   Sÿ(Ð@ …Àtƒ|$pu3À@ë3Àh¬ê@ PèýÿÿŒ$ˆ    0  YYjpD$tPj   SÿÐ@ 
hÌê@ PèÙüÿÿjD^VD$4WPè8  ƒÄ‰t$(‹54Ð@ jöÿÖPD$dèôþÿÿÇ$ìê@ Pè¢üÿÿYYjõÿÖPD$hè×þÿÿÇ$ë@ Pè…üÿÿYYjôÿÖPD$lèºþÿÿÇ$$ë@ PèhüÿÿYYjh}@ ÇD$\   ÿ<Ð@ 
D$PD$,PWWWjWWÿt$4WÿÐ@ ÿt$h@ë@ Pè&üÿÿ‹D$,ƒÄÿt$£hA SÿÐ@ ÿt$ÿDÐ@ jÿÿt$ÿÐ@ D$Pÿt$ÿ Ð@ hdë@ PèßûÿÿYYÿt$ÿ Ð@ ÌU‹ìQSVW‹=8Ñ@ »ˆë@ Sÿuë%F‰Eü· 
f…Àtƒø"tjPèÐ  YY…ÀuSÿuüÿ×‹ð…öuÓ3À…ö•Àh”ë@ Pè{ûÿÿ‹}YYƒÆfƒ?"j[u3Àfƒ>"hØë@ ”ÀPèVûÿÿ3ÀYf‰
```

Answer (score 2):

Python files are normally source files (.py). If you have been given a compiled python file (.pyc), [Easy Python Decompiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/) can generate Python source code (.py) from your compiled script (.pyc).